# Pi, Matlab Symbolic math toolbox have a bug?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Hello i have one question. When I calculate a division in matlab: x/(pi.^2)

```
syms x
x/(pi.^2)
ans =
(281474976710656*v)/2778046668940015
```

the correct answer is x/9.8696, so why is matlab giving me this result?

Is it a bug?

Comment: that's the rational approximation MATLAB is giving you. No it is not a bug, use the numerical approximation symbolic toolbox function ( it is N[] in mathematica, forget what matlab's is)

Comment: Indeed.  Note that `281474976710656/2778046668940015 ~= 1/9.8696`. The symbolic math toolbox tries to preserve as much precision as possible by deferring floating point computations.  Since pi is inherently irrational, it uses this approximation.

Comment: `double(blah)` from http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html

Comment: also note that if you're doing symbolic calculations with pi, etc, use `sym('pi')` to get a symbolic representation of pi rather than an approximation

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the vpa() command "Variable-precision arithmetic". Check this code:

```
syms x real;       % define x as a real symbolic variable (not a complex variable)
vpa( x/(pi.^2), 5) % second argument define number of significant digits
```

For trigonometric expressions involving pi, it is sometimes good to define sym('pi'):

```
syms x real;
pi_s = sym('pi');
expr = x/pi_s^2
```

I try to always use the 'real' tag when using the symbolic toolbox. If you do not use it you are going to see a lot of complex conjugates and other things that are not important for your problem, because x is probably real variable.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

No it is not a bug:

```
2778046668940015/281474976710656 = 9.8696
```

Comment: I see, No it is not a bug it's the precision for rational approximation. thanks!